# response.getOutputStream used on MySQL request throwing IllegalStateException in JSP

Tags: java, mysql, servlets, outputstream, illegalstateexception

I'm faced with what I find to be an odd problem. I'm trying to create a website that dynamically creates a "forum-thread"-ish page by retrieving and displaying data from a MySQL server. This data can be of two types: Plain text or an image file (stored as a BLOB). At the time of testing, we have 3 entries in the database - 1 text, 1 picture, 1 text. We are using JSP and servlets to retrieve and display the data. The text entries are written just fine, but when trying to display the pictures, we keep getting IllegalStateExceptions from our OutputStream instance - i.e., it will run the code up until we try to instantiate the OutputStream, and then throw the exception.

We figured it has something to do with multithreading, but after trying using synchronized and specific reentrantlocks, we still get the exception. I should mention, that if we try to run the "get-image" part of the code as a seperate servlet and not as part of the JSP, it displays the image just fine.

The servlet code looks as follows:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Blob;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletOutputStream;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class listConversation
 */
@WebServlet("/ListConversation")
public class ListConversation extends HttpServlet
{

    @Override
    protected synchronized void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        try
        {
            String connectionURL = [our database URL, username and password];
            String myDriver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";

            Class.forName(myDriver).newInstance();

            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL);

            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();

            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT ID, Content1 FROM Conversations WHERE ConversationID=587 ORDER BY Date ASC");

            res.setContentType("text/html");
            PrintWriter out = res.getWriter();

            out.print("<hr>");

            while (rs.next())
            {
                out.print("<b>Besked</b><br/>" + rs.getString("Content1") + "<br/><br/>");

                try {

                    System.out.println("Try-block started.");
                    Statement stmt2 = con.createStatement();
                    System.out.println("Statement created.");
                    ResultSet rs2 = stmt2.executeQuery("SELECT Content2 FROM Conversations WHERE ID = 4");
                    System.out.println("Statement executed.");
                    ServletOutputStream outStream = res.getOutputStream();
                    System.out.println("Outputstream initialized.");
                    Blob image;
                            if (rs2.next()) {
                                image = rs2.getBlob(1);
                                System.out.println("Image created.");
                            } else {
                                res.setContentType("text/html");
                                out.println("h4><font color='red'>image not found for given id</font></h4>");
                                        return;
                            }
                            res.setContentType("image/gif");
                            InputStream in = image.getBinaryStream();
                            int length = (int) image.length();
                            int bufferSize = 1024;
                            byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
                            System.out.println("Initializing...");
                            while ((length = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                                outStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
                            }
                            System.out.println("Image streamed.");
                            in.close();
                            stmt2.close();
                            rs2.close();
                            outStream.close();
                            System.out.println("Closing.");
                            out.flush();
                }
                catch(IllegalStateException e)
                {
                    System.out.println("Darn OutputStreams...");
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    res.setContentType("text/html");
                    out.println("<h4><font color='red'>Image Display Error=" + e.getMessage() +
                            "</font></h4>");
                    return;
                }

                out.print("<hr>");
            }

            stmt.close();
            con.close();

            }
        catch (SQLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }


    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        doGet(req,res);
    }


}
```

The console output is:

```
Try-block started. 
Statement created. 
Statement executed.
Darn OutputStreams...
```

as we have three entries with the ConversationID of 587. Content1 is text, Content2 are BLOBS.

Any ideas or corrections would be much appreciated. Thank you :D

Comment: print the stackTrace in the catch clause to know the exact exception

Comment: It says right in the docs that "either `getWriter` or `getOutputStream` may be called to write the body, but not both." You already called `getWriter`, so it's probably an illegal state exception, but you swallow all exception information, which seems a poor decision.

Comment: @Rakesh -  We added the syso's for our own debugging purposes, but I can see how that does not help you help me, my bad. 

The stack trace looks as follows: 
`Try-block started.
Statement created.
Statement executed.
java.lang.IllegalStateException
Darn OutputStreams...
 at org.apache.jasper.runtime.ServletResponseWrapperInclude.getOutputStream(ServletResponseWrapperInclude.java:65)
 at offentlig.ListConversation.doGet(ListConversation.java:59)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
....`

Comment: @Dave Newton - You are right. How do you suggest we get around that? We just tried closing the writer just before the second try clause, opening it again in the end of the while loop but received following stack trace: 
`[java.lang.IllegalStateException: Exception occurred when flushing data] with root cause
java.io.IOException: Stream closed`

As far as I know, we need the writer for the text, and the outputStream for the BLOBS? Thanks

Comment: The issue is that you're doing this wrong; the servlet should set up data *for* the JSP. The JSP would show the text, and make a new request for the image, like normal.

Answer (score 0):

You can't call response.getWriter() and response.getOutputStream() within the same response. The call

```
PrintWriter out = res.getWriter();
```

has already "claimed" the response so to speak so when you call

```
ServletOutputStream outStream = res.getOutputStream();
```

you get the exception.

Comment: Thanks. You and Dave Newton are both right - but how do I print both text and pictures if I can't use both?

Comment: Dave's last comment would be the solution for your problem. The servlet should prepare the data that the jsp will be displaying. You could create a class that represents a forum post, the servlet would create an object of that class and then redirect to the jsp that could then use the class to display the data on the page.